# saving data so it does not restart when I run the program again

Tags: python

I want to create a debt collector program. I want to be able to save the data so when I close it I don't have to start over. For example, if account = 100 and I make a payment of 20 that then makes the account = 80. I want to save this new variable so that when I run it again it does not start me at 100 again.

So far I've tried:

```
def takePayment():
    account = 0
    take_payment = input("how mych")
    sum = float(account) + float(take_payment)
    print("The total now is $", sum)
takePayment()
```

Comment: You could pickle the variable or use a database?

Comment: Just added a bit of grammar and clarification and capitalized some I's.

Comment: Google "saving state".

Answer (score 0):

You could quite easily write it into a file [see here for details](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

For example in your code you could add:

```
file = open('log', 'w')
file.write(str(sum))
file.close()
```

To write the value of the `sum`

Then when you wanted to read the values you could use:

```
f = open('log', 'r')
account = f.read()
f.close()
```

Then convert the values and use them normally.